# put a vector in a matrix in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a vector of points and I want  to put the value 255 for each point in a matrix , here what I've tried, it didn't work

```
.............................
cv::Mat result;
result =cv::Mat::zeros(frame.size(),CV_8UC1);
std::vector<cv::Point2f> vectorOFPoints;
...............................
    for ( int i = 0 ; vectorOFPoints.size()-1;i++){
                result.at<uchar>(vectorOFPoints.at<i>) = 255; 
            }
```

any idea how can I do this ? 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You line in the loop is wrong, it should be

```
result.at<uchar>(vectorOFPoints.at<cv::Point2f>(i)) = 255;
```

But you may need you point type to be cv::Point instead of cv::Point2f (Don't know how it works with cv::Point2f)

```
std::vector<cv::Point> vectorOFPoints;
/* Code */
/* Loop */
result.at<uchar>(vectorOFPoints.at<cv::Point>(i)) = 255;
```

I think this may work (Didn't tested though)

Comment: it didn't work I get an  error at cv::Point2f saying that type  name isn't allowed ??

Comment: but the program crashes after ending the for loop

Comment: What is imageCorners ? IT's possible that this type isn't allowed because a matrix need a integer point. Try to replace cv::Point2f by cv::Point

Comment: I had a problem with my loop I forgot to put i = vectoOfPOint and that why the program crashes